# Last column input width of 100% overflows container with Blueprint CSS

Tags: css, blueprint-css

How do I correct for an `<input>` tag with a `width: 100%` in the last column of a Blueprint CSS layout extending over the right edge of the container?

I have tried applying a right margin to the `last` class but that pushes the column down to the next row.

Comment: please show your code for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to go Blueprint all the way and remove the `width: 100%` and use the `span-x` classes to control the width of the input elements.